# Windows 10 laptop doesn't connect to internet via wifi

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I have an HP Pavilion laptop running windows 10. Suddenly it stopped connecting to the Internet through WiFi. Meaning, I can connect to the WiFi but computer can't reach the web. I've formatted and re-installed a fresh copy of Windows 10, but I am still having the issue!

But the laptop's WiFi adapter (Ralink) works fine when LAN gaming.
Means laptop WiFi adapter is working right?

What could be a possible solution?

I tried different WiFi networks at my home / university and public WiFi non of these working with my laptop.

On my WiFi status It shows

IPV4 connectivity: internet
IPV6 connectivity: no network access

Comment: Yes, it means the WiFi adapter is working and what you have is probably a DNS issue. You should try rebooting the router (as this is unrelated to the OS) before anything else.

Comment: @MichaelBay I tried few wifi networks (home / university / public wifi) but non of these working. So the problem is with the laptop

Comment: I think the upvoted answer is worth to try.

Answer (score 3):

> Means I can connect to the wifi but computer can't reach the internet.

This looks like the adapter can't resolve Internet addresses. I would recommend you to open a command line window (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> `cmd`) and then test this:

1. `ipconfig` to see what IP your gateway have (e.g. 192.168.0.1) and to check, if your WLAN adapter got a valid IP address
2. `ping 192.168.0.1` (your gateway) to see, if there is a response.
3. If the ping was successful you could ping to the google DNS with `ping 8.8.8.8`
4. If that was successful, try to `ping google.com`, if you get an error, then most probably the DNS servers are wrong.
5. To see what DNS are set, you could do a `ipconfig /all` and scroll to the DNS section of your WLAN adapter.
6. To set DNS you could follow this steps: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-dns-servers-in-windows-2626242. You could use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (google DNS) or set it to automatically, if something wrong is set.

Comment: I can ping google.com and any other site. But when I tried to open a site in web browsers it can’t reach the site. Says request timed out

Comment: Is there any other things I can check ?

Comment: What browser are you using? Could you test with Internet Explorer, and Firefox and a third one like Edge or Chrome? Is it the same with every browser? Check also the proxy settings in "contrlo panel" - "internet options": 1st: http://image.chromefans.org/i100/id127/chrome-proxy-server-1.png then delete untick everything at "proxy" https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0bxl.png

Comment: Have you tried with another OS on the same machine? (like a linux live image)

Comment: @chloesoe I don’t have any proxy. I even tried re installing fresh copy of Windows. - yes I tried different browsers.

Comment: You reinstalled Windows completely? Strange. I would have checked the windows firewall if the outgoing port 80 or 443 is blocked. Perhaps port 8080 works, test here: http://portquiz.net:8080/. Have you checked on your router? Perhaps the MAC address of your wifi is blocked, but then it's strange you're able to ping into the Internet.

Comment: Or try to deactivate IPv6: https://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/IPV6Disabled_thumb.jpg

Answer (score -2):

Initially check device manager , network adapter  whether a correct wifi driver is installed in your laptop. If its fine check your router page to see the dhcp settings in order to get the internet working

Comment: If it works in the LAN then it's not a drivers issue.